# Overriding Spring @PropertySource by @Import

Tags: spring, properties

I have a property `test=default` in class DefaultConfig, and I'm making them available using @PropertySource annotation.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:default.properties")
public class DefaultConfig {}
```

I then want to be able to override to `test=override`, which is in a different properties file in class OverrideConfig, so I again use @PropertySource.

```
@Configuration
@Import(DefaultConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:override.properties")
public class OverrideConfig {}
```

I configure a test to prove that it works.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={OverrideConfig.class})
public class TestPropertyOverride {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Test
    public void propertyIsOverridden() {
        assertEquals("override", env.getProperty("test"));
    }

}
```

Except of course it does not.

`org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[override]> but was:<[default]>`

Maxing out debug, I can see what's happening:

```
StandardEnvironment:107 - Adding [class path resource [default.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
StandardEnvironment:107 - Adding [class path resource [override.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
```

It seems backwards. Am I making a simple mistake or misthinking this, or would you expect the properties defined by an @PropertySource in an @Import-ed configuration class to be overridden by properties defined in am @PropertySource in the @Import-ing class?

Comment: What's probably happening is that the annotations on your `OverrideConfig` class are being evaluated first and so `test=override`, then the `DefaultConfig` class is imported and its annotations are evaluated and `test` being overwritten to `default`

Comment: Raised issue https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10409

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution by [Helder Sousa](https://jira.spring.io/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=htmsousa), written as [a comment of the JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10409?focusedCommentId=101393&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-101393) created by the OP:

> The behaviour available in spring xml (one xml importing another xml) is achievable using nested configurations:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @PropertySource("classpath:default.properties")
> public class DefaultConfig {}
> ```
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @PropertySource("classpath:override.properties")
> public class OverrideConfig {
>
>     @Configuration
>     @Import(DefaultConfig.class)
>     static class InnerConfiguration {}
>
> }
> ```
>
> With this setup, the properties will be gathered in the proper order.

Answer (score 2):

Today with Spring 4 you can use this:

```
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:/config/test.properties")
```

And this can be used to use and eventually override properties for the junit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:/config/test.properties")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently struggling with a similar case in Spring 3.1 but I'm using a different approach to override properties, because `@PropertySource` does not support optional property files:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:default.properties")
public class BaseConfig {

  @Inject
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() throws IOException {
    Resource runtimeProps = context.getResource("classpath:override.properties");
    if (runtimeProps.exists()) {
      MutablePropertySources sources = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
      sources.addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource(runtimeProps));
    }
  }
...
```

It seems that `@Import` does not cause any specific order of `@Configuration` instantiation whatsoever besides the order dictated by normal bean dependencies. A way to force such an order is to inject the base `@Configuration` instance itself as a dependency. Could you try:

```
@Configuration
@Import(DefaultConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:override.properties")
public class OverrideConfig {

  @Inject
  private DefaultConfig defaultConfig;

  ...
}
```

Does this help?
And maybe the new `ContextHierarchy` annotation could be of help here also but I didn't try this one out so far.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't help. As far as I can tell, this behaviour is just how it is unless the Spring folks agree to change it. Case raised.

Comment: Amen. As much as I loathe XML wiring, I do miss `<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true"  
        location="classpath:base.config,file:override.config" />`

Answer (score 1):

You could enforce the loading order of your properties like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:default.properties","classpath:override.properties"})
public class OverrideConfig {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and succeeded in just declaring also the default property in my custom configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Import(DefaultConfig.class)
@PropertySource({"classpath:default.properties", "classpath:override.properties"})
public class OverrideConfig {}
```